# CURL only fetch the first line of the file if the url is wrapped in quotes

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I am using CURL to download a file from the internet in a shell script on a Linux server. The url is coded as a string in the shell script.  But I am only getting the first line of the file instead of the whole file content. When I tested the curl command directly in the command line on the Linux server, if the url is wrapped in single or double quote, only one line of the file is downloaded. If the url is not wrapped in quotes, then the entire file is downloaded.  But I have to code the url as a string in the shell script.  Could any one suggest the cause of the problem or how I could get around with this issue?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Show code that demonstrates the problem as part of your question. However, your answer is likely to be "yes, that's what the syntax requires". When you run a command in bash, the command only has access to its arguments as they exist *after being parsed into an array of C strings by the user's interactive shell*. Any information on what form they had before that parsing is lost.

Comment: So, you **can't** just override the parsing process; it's already finished before your script was run.

Comment: See http://shellcheck.net/ warning [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) with more on why quoting is not optional in shell.